# Асинхронная загрузка javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Добрый день. Решил ускорить сайт. Скрипты были перенесены в **подвал**. jQuery грузится из CDN в **хедере**:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript" async ></script>
```

Но есть проблема. Всё что связано с jQuery пишет:

```
$ is not defined
```

Прочитал разницу между `async` и `defer`. Насколько я понял, **defer** скрипты выполняются в самый последний момент, когда весь HTML получен и распарсен, в то время как **async**  будет обработан сразу после загрузки. Тогда я решил добавить defer ко всем скриптам в футер, но это работает через раз. Иногда ошибки "not defined" есть, иногда нету. Как исправить?

Comment: А в теле страницы нет других скриптов? jQuery загружается без defer/async?

Comment: Писал-писал, и опубликовал без примера моей загрузки jQuery.  Да, jquery грузится через async

Comment: уберите `async` у jQuery.

Comment: если убрать async, то GooglePageSpeed ругается на блокирующие скрипты!

Comment: Переместите все в подвал, да и async нужно убрать

Comment: @dantey89, поместите его в футер первым, но уберите `async`.

Comment: @Visman как вариант)

Answer (score 2):

Дэвид Флэнаган - JavaScript. Подробное руководство:

> Оба атрибута, `defer` и `async`, сообщают броузеру, что данный сценарий не
>   использует метод `document.write()` и не генерирует содержимое документа, и что броузер может продолжать разбор и отображение документа, пока сценарий загружается.
>
> Атрибут `defer` заставляет броузер отложить выполнение сценария до момента, когда документ будет **загружен, проанализирован и станет готов к выполнению** операций. Атрибут `async` заставляет броузер выполнить сценарий, как только это станет возможно, но не блокирует разбор документа на время загрузки сценария.
>
> Если тег `<script>` имеет оба атрибута, броузер, поддерживающий оба этих атрибута, отдаст предпочтение атрибуту `async` и проигнорирует атрибут `defer`.
>
> Обратите внимание, что отложенные сценарии выполняются в **порядке их 
>   следования в документе**. Асинхронные сценарии выполняются сразу же, как только 
>   будут загружены, т. е. они могут выполняться в **произвольном порядке**.

Таким образом, я советую оставить все скрипты в заголовке (зачем портить код), и везде, где используется jquery, и подключению самой библиотеки прописать атрибут `defer`. Скрипты где jquery не используется (то есть они не зависят от подключения других скриптов) можно подключать с атрибутом `async`, для максимально быстрой загрузки. Отложенные скрипты (те что с `defer`) надо подключать начиная с jquery, чтобы не было ошибок.

Вообще лично я использую всегда `defer` - не блокирует загрузку и точно знаешь последовательность выполнения (также DOM модель уже загружена и не надо использовать `window.onload`).

Answer (score 1):

У меня та же проблема на моем проекте. Народ писал, что нужно закодить последовательность загрузки скриптов в строку, где грузиться сам jquery. Читал я это на портале http://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0+javascript, посвященном ускорению и масштабированию.
Пока у меня стоит костыль. Сам jquery грузится сверху без асинхронной загрузки. Если у тебя нет модулей анимации, то должно все работать.
Статью я постараюсь найти.Может кто из гуру JS подскажет, как найти эти функции.Но как я понял, тебе нужно найти функции, которые используют $ и заставить их ждать Jquery.
Ну а пока вот мой стиль подключения:

```
<script src="//wob.su/design/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("head").append("<link href='//wob.su/design/assets/css/green.css' rel='stylesheet' title='Color' >");
    $("head").append("<link href='//wob.su/design/assets/css/owl.carousel.css' rel='stylesheet' >");
    $("head").append("<link href='//wob.su/design/assets/css/owl.transitions.css' rel='stylesheet' >");
    $("head").append("<link href='//wob.su/design/assets/css/animate.min.css' rel='stylesheet' >");
    $("head").append("<link href='//wob.su/design/assets/fonts/fontello.css' rel='stylesheet' />");
});
```

</script>
            </script>

```
    <script src="//wob.su/design/assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js" async></script>
    <script src="//wob.su/design/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//wob.su/design/assets/js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js" async></script>
    <script src="//wob.su/design/assets/js/skrollr.min.js" async></script>
    <script src="//wob.su/design/assets/js/skrollr.stylesheets.min.js" async></script>
    <script src="//wob.su/design/assets/js/waypoints.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="//wob.su/design/assets/js/waypoints-sticky.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="//wob.su/design/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="//wob.su/design/assets/js/jquery.isotope.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="//wob.su/design/assets/js/jquery.easytabs.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="//wob.su/design/assets/js/viewport-units-buggyfill.js" ></script>
    <script src="//wob.su/design/assets/js/scripts.js" async></script>
```